# Is there a word that means simple but not easy?

Tags: single-word-requests

Often I find myself or others describing a concept that is simple to explain, but difficult to execute. I end up saying "it's really simple, just not easy" way too often for my tastes. Is there a word that expresses this idea well?

Comment: Check this topic, maybe it helps; http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76906/something-simple-and-yet-complex

Comment: I need some context!  In some contexts, you could say *elegant*.  Here's a phrase: *straightforward but tricky to get it right*.

Answer (score 6):

Something that is simple to explain, but difficult to execute can be called ***tricky***.

M-W:

> **[tricky](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tricky)**
>   *adjective*
>
> **2 a** :  **giving a deceptive impression of easiness**, simplicity, or order :  ticklish : *a **tricky** path through the swamp*

Answer (score 1):

One word that may be suitable is [***awkward***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/awkward).

> **awkward** [adjective]
>   ​
>   difficult to use, do, or deal with:
>
> - It's an awkward corner, so take it slowly.